# Не срабатывает условие внутри функции с переданными аргументами

Tags: python, функции

Я передаю в функцию пять аргументов неравных нулю. По неизвестной мне причине условие `if max_speed_1 or accelerate_1 == 0` выполняется всегда вне зависимости от того, передаю ли я эти аргументы или нет.

Почему так происходит и как это можно исправить?

```
def players_and_enemies_time(max_speed,accelerate,max_distance,max_speed_1 = 0,accelerate_1 = 0):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    current_distance = 0
    time_at_moment = 0
    speed_at_moment = 0

    while current_distance < max_distance:
        time_at_moment += 1
        speed_at_moment = accelerate * (time_at_moment**(1/3))
        if max_speed < speed_at_moment:
            speed_at_moment = max_speed
        current_distance += speed_at_moment

    x = time_at_moment
    current_distance = 0
    time_at_moment = 0
    speed_at_moment = 0

    if max_speed_1 or accelerate_1 == 0:
        return x
    else:
        while current_distance < max_distance:
            time_at_moment += 1
            speed_at_moment = accelerate_1 * (time_at_moment**(1/3))
            if max_speed_1 < speed_at_moment:
                speed_at_moment = max_speed_1
            current_distance += speed_at_moment
        y = time_at_moment

        return x,y

print(players_and_enemies_time(180,45,20000,168,55))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if max_speed_1 == 0 or accelerate_1 == 0
```